# Why are deleted files coming back after a new write to file? Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app in swift that logs sensor data to a txt file.  When I have an event occur that needs to be logged I create the filename

```
    func createNewLogFile (){

    // Create a new file name
    currentFileName = "log\(NSDate()).txt"    
    //get the path
    let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

    //create the file
    _ = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

}
```

After the file is created I write data to the new file like this:

```
 func writeData (data: String){

    // get the path to document directory
    let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let filePath = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)


    //get the data to be logged
    let stringLocation  = data
    let stringData = stringLocation.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!


    //look to see if the file exist
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath.path!) {
        do {

            //seek to the end of the file to append data
            let fileHandle = try NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: filePath)
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.writeData(stringData)
            fileHandle.closeFile()


        } catch {

            print("Can't open fileHandle \(error)")

        }
    } else {

        do {

            // write to new file
            try stringData.writeToURL(filePath, options: .DataWritingAtomic)

        } catch {

            print("Can't write to new file \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

When I delete the files (from a different ViewController or the same, I tried both)

I am calling this DeleteAllFiles

```
func deleteAllFiles (Extension: String){


    let dirs = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let dir = dirs[0]

    do {
        let fileList = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(dir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        //return fileList as [String]

        for elements in fileList{
            do{
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(elements)

                print("old Files has been removed")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

    }catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

I then refresh the list and the files seem to be gone.(even when I go back and forth between views)  However, when I write a new file and refresh the list the files are back with the new file.

This even happens when I delete them from iTunes using the shared files feature.
Any ideas on why this is happening?  I am not getting any helpful error messages.

Comment: The file will be [re]created each time it is opened for writing. It is likely that an "unexpected" write occurs.

Comment: It's not being recreated when I write. I'm feeding in the current file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the problem.
When I was creating the file I actually only meant to create the file name. There was no reason to actually create the file at this time.  I am creating the actual file when I write to it.

```
func createNewLogFile (){

    // Create a new file name
    currentFileName = "log\(NSDate()).txt" 

    //Removed creating actual file code   

}
```